# How to resize the height of this site?

Tags: jquery, resize, bxslider

I have a site that is basically a `<ul>`and 5 `<li>`I just used the jQuery bxSlider to make it slide from side to side however since the content in one of the `<li>` is very long the site looks that way on any other element even if the only contents in the other `<li>`is an image. So I wanted to resize the height (force it) using jQuery and doing:

```
if($('#slider1:nth-child(0)').is(':visible'))
            alert("1"); 
        else if($('#slider1:nth-child(1)').is(':visible'))
            alert("2");
```

but right now testing I always get the 2nd alert even if I'm in the last child. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how I can accomplish this? my HTML is pretty simple it's:

```
<ul id="slider1" style="border=100px;">
          <li>
            <div id="menu" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="picsHOME/home0.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="picsHOME/home1.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="picsHOME/home2.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="picsHOME/home4.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="picsHOME/home5.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="picsHOME/home6.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="picsHOME/home7.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="picsHOME/home8.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div id="nosotros">
                <img src="nosotros.jpg" alt="" /> <p>
                <img src="NOSOTROS-MISION.jpg" alt="" /><p>
                <img src="FOTOS-NOMBRES.jpg" alt=""  />

            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div id="servicios">
                <img src="servicios.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="SERVICIOStest.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
          <img src="portafolio2.jpg" /><p>
          <a href="http://issuu.com/citro_ids/docs/citro_ids_portafolio_2012?mode=window&backgroundColor=%23222222" />
          <img src="port_link.png" /> <p></a>
          <img src="VERSION-DESCARGABLE2.jpg" />
          </li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the jQuery docs:

Because jQuery's implementation of :nth-child(n) is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

You should start with `:nth-child(1)`

If you want to use a 0 based approach:

```
if($('#slider1 li:eq(0)').is(':visible'))
        alert("1"); 
    else if($('#slider1:eq(1)').is(':visible'))
        alert("2");
```

The `:eq` will give you the 1, and 2nd li's respectively.